# How to find changes in proportions using regression?

Tags: econometrics, proportion

I want to test the hypothesis that the expansion of lending institutions changed the goals that households obtained their loans for. In other words, say in 1950 the breakup was:

- 33% got loans for "education"
- 33% got loans for "housing"
- 33% got loans for "medical"

Then in 1951 there was a government policy that led to banks expanding branches into previously underserved areas. In 1960, after lots of branches have been opened, the breakdown of loan purposes is something else (say 40%, 50%, 10%).

The problem is what to use as my dependent variable, and what to use as my underlying distribution.

1. Focus on the raw number of people who got these loans. Then a few standard linear regressions seem appropriate.
2. Treat each proportion separately, and run 3 logit models.
3. Treat each proportion separately, run 3 beta regression
4. Treat the proportions as a whole, which impose the condition that they all add to 100%. That leads me to something called a Dirichlet distribution (cf., [this presentation (pdf)](http://www.uni-tuebingen.de/fileadmin/Uni_Tuebingen/Fakultaeten/SozialVerhalten/Institut_fuer_Soziologie/Dokumente/Pdf_Dateien/Buis/UKsug06.pdf)).

4 seems to be the ideal.  My question is, broadly, what would be the best method?

Comment: Wouldn't the "ideal" method be the "best method"? Can you clarify what you still want to know? Are you just asking for confirmation that your hunch is correct?

Comment: I guess I am asking if my hunch is correct. I don't know if the Dirichlet distribution is the best way to do it - it just seemed to fit. This is the first time I'm dealing with proportion data and am not sure how best to approach it.